# I want to know how to make a square root in python so that when the user types a number it gives the square root of that number to the user

Tags: python-2.7

Please help me with this question i have been stuck on it for a few hours:

How to give the user the square root of the number he types? Hope some people out in this world know how to do this. I searched on the internet for hours and to my avail got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math # So that we can use the sqrt() function
user_inp = float(input())  # takes in user input value and converts it to float
print (math.sqrt(float(user_inp))) #shows the square root answer to the screen
```